# How do I move a peaceful monster out of the way that's being just a bit too heroic?

Tags: nethack

So, I got to the last level of Sokoban, and then this happened:

[image: screenshot]

That dwarf in the doorway is friendly, and it's great that he's trying to be a hero for me and all, but now I'm kind of just stuck here. The enemies won't attack the dwarf, and the dwarf won't attack them.

If it was a pet, I would just displace it, but this brave dwarf insists on staying to protect me. I'd prefer not to kill it because of the alignment penalty. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the door still exist?  If so, then the dwarf is stuck too; you can't move into or out of a doorway diagonally.  If you just move up a step, the dwarf should be able to move out of the doorway, giving you room to fight.  If the enemies stop coming briefly, you can then close the door and kick it down to allow freer movement.

If the door doesn't still exist... maybe walk away and come back in a minute or so.  There's a good chance you'll find the dwarf walking up the pathway (pushed along by a crowd of enemies), and you can wait at the top for him to come out with the crowd of enemies behind him.  He's a dwarf, so he'll do it slowly, but he will do it.

Comment: Good call! I used my key to unlock the door so that the sleeping monsters inside wouldn't wake up. I was hoping for some kind of strategy other than "go away and come back later," but okay, thanks, trying that!

Comment: [Thank you Mr. Gnome for saving me from Team Ant](http://i.stack.imgur.com/36mwG.png) :P (It worked!)

Comment: Note that taking one step up and waiting on the diagonal would probably have sufficed - you can't walk through a door on the diagonal, but you can still attack or close doors diagonally.